# How to show a point on a bing map with a MapPolyLine object?

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I have created a MapPolyLine object (from Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF) containing a location collection and I display it on a map. I can see a line.

But it doesn't run if the location collection of the MapPolyLine counts only one point.

Do I have absolutely to use the objects from namespace System.Windows.Shapes to mark my location point on the map ? Or is there another way with the MapPolyLine object ? Does it exist a MapPoint object or similar ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you are asking. If you want to show a single point on the map you should be using a Pushpin or a UIElement of some sort and adding it to the children property of the map.

Polylines and MapPolylines always require two points in order to be drawn. If you are in a situation where you only have one coordinate and you plan to add additional coordinates to a polyline over time (i.e. drawing tools, or automated process such as tracking), then add the first coordinate to the polyline twice.